# "sdk platform tools component is missing"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was following the instructions, word-for-word, as on Android's website: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

I already have `Eclipse Juno` on which I develop Java applications. For my coursework I need `Android SDK`. I followed the instructions till adding a new software and restarting Eclipse.

Then I got error messages saying:

```
sdk platform tools component is missing
```

They were two dialog boxes that went away when I clicked close. *Very obvious* :P
[image]

And in my Eclipse console I have this:

```
[2013-06-10 16:40:09 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: C:\Users\LittleJavaChild\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe 
[2013-06-10 16:40:09 - DDMS] DDMS files not found: C:\Users\LittlejavaChild\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
```

I have no idea what to do next.

**Please help me set up the SDK.**

Also, how do I remove the newly installed software if I want to repeat the steps on Android's site again ?

Comment: Ok, found the solution :-). If any1 would like to still answer, I will accept it. :)

Comment: How do you solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the little Android Android SDK button

[image]

And make sure the top 3 things are installed

[image]

Comment: Done, sir, is that all I need ??? Are there any paths to set as in case of normal Java ?

Comment: I think so. You will also need to download at least one of the platforms (like Android 4.2.2 SDK Platform, documentation, samples, etc.)

Comment: Yes, all that is done. I downloaded the latest one with samples, docs, etc :-)