# sdk platform tools component is missing when i copied the android sdk path

Tags: android, eclipse

Getting "SDK platform tools component is missing" when I copied Android sdk to different path. and "Failed to get required ADT components etc..."

Initially I installed Android SDK on C drive and it worked fine with Eclipse

As my C drive is full, I copied Android sdk to D drive, and then I tried to configure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable to the new D drive path.

After that when I launch Eclipse it is complaining saying "sdk platform tools component is missing"

Am i missing something?

Comment: C drive, D drive (vs. driver).

Answer (score 0):

### OPTION 1

From this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17022803/3922207):

Click the little Android Android SDK button:

[image: open SDK]

And install all the components on the Tools folder:

[image: install]

### OPTION 2

If Eclipse still complaining saying "sdk platform tools component is missing", you can try option 2.

Open eclipse **>** select Window menu **>** Preference **>** Android **>** browse your sdk location **>** ok.

[image]