# "sdk platform tools component is missing”

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sdk-manager

I was reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022643/sdk-platform-tools-component-is-missing) but I can't solve my problem.

I have Eclipse Mars on which I am developing my Java project to the university. For this I need Android SDK. I followed the instructions till adding a new software and restarting Eclipse.

Then I got error messages saying the same that the before thread

I try to follow the steps which are explained in the same thread but then, I got another error message saying

***Fetching URL***:    https: //dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml       **Validate XML:**       https: //dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml       **Parse XML**:       https: //dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/x86/addon-x86.xml       Found Google APIs (x86 System Image), Android API 19, revision 14       Done loading packages. Preparing to install archives Downloading       Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 22 Failed to create directory       C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp Downloading Android      SDK Build-tools, revision 22.0.1 Failed to create directory       C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp 
**Done. Nothing was installed.**

I don't know how to solve this problem, **I need help to set up the SDK**
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the messages about some failures:

> ```
> Preparing to install archives Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 22 
> Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp 
> Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 22.0.1 
> Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp 
> Done. Nothing was installed.
> ```

The process could not create directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp`. 
It looks like the user with which you are installing has no permission to create a directory there.

Either rerun the installer with another user that has write permission there (admin?),
or change the target location of the Android SDK files to another location where your user has write permission.

Comment: Thanks you so much! I re-install the Android SDK with admin permissions and then, eclipse works!

Comment: Hi Janos, thanks for the answer but I am using the admin account (the only account) for this computer and yet it still tells me: "Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp 
Done. Nothing was installed."  Do you have any other idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @Tomer, what if you create the directory manually and then rerun the installer?

Comment: Hi thanks for the fast response, I followed your proposal to create the directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp" manualy and try to download angain, but still I get the same error: "Failed to create directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp"

Comment: @Tomer Strange. What if you specify another location? Something without spaces, to minimize problems.